# Wayland blanks screen but does not put monitors in standby mode

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, wayland

When using Wayland on 22.04, screen blanks but remains on with a bright background light.

I changed to X11 and when screen blanks, it correctly goes to standby mode.

Does anybody have the same experience? Seems a wayland problem to me.

Equipment: Intel NUC - Intel_R_ Client Systems NUC7i3DNHE, Dell and Acer KA220HQ monitors both connected via HDMI
Ubuntu 22.04 running stock drivers as installed.